# Undefined symbol error in GAS 32bit Assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler

I wrote a GAS 32bit source code named 'test.s' like below:

```
.global _main
.data
    message: .string "Hello, World!\n\0"
.text
_main:
    # BEGIN Stack Frame
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    # Call Unix System Call - write(fd, buf, count)
    pushl $1 # fd = stdout
    pushl $message # buf = message
    pushl $14 # count = 14
    call write

    # END Stack Frame
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp

    xor %eax, %eax # return 0
    ret
```

and I run a command in macOS 10.14.4 (Mojave) like below:

```
$ gcc -m32 test.s -otest
```

Then an error was occured:

```
ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (removed from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "write", referenced from:
    _main in test-8c5cf2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I don't exactly know what the reason is...

Comment: As the first line of the error says, 32 bit is no longer supported apparently.

Comment: Mac prefixes / decorates C symbol names with a leading `_`.  That's why you had to use `_main` in asm to define the C `main` function.